# getAllMembers from Elements does not return Parent's member annotations

Tags: java, annotations, annotation-processing

`getAllMembers` from [java.lang.Model.Util.Elements](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/lang/model/util/Elements.html#getAllMembers(javax.lang.model.element.TypeElement)) does not return Parent's member annotations

Example:

```
public class Foo {

@QueryParam("firstname")
private String name;

public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}}



public class Bar extends Foo{

@QueryParam("address")
private String address;

public String getAddress() {
    return address;
}

public void setAddress(String address) {
    this.address = address;
}}
```

From `AnnotationProcessor` when I try to read the members of TypeElement Bar, by using `Elements getAllMembers(Bar as TypeElement)` it gives me right members, however, I can't read annotations of the Parent class i.e. In this case, annotations "QueryParam" of Foo class member "name" which is the parent of Bar.

Any idea what am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

Your superclass field is private - getAllMembers returns all inherited/declared members. So bar does not inherit the field 'name' or its anntoation.